# Are two base cases necessary for proving inequalities with induction?

Tags: inequality, induction

If we were asked to prove a discrete inequality using induction, such as proving $5^n \geq 1+4n$ for $n\geq 1$, do we need separate base cases to prove the statement is true for the equality case and the inequality case?

For example, $n=1$ proves the equality part of the statement and $n=2$ proves the (strict) inequality part.

Comment: No, there is no need for that. In fact, its not always possible to provide that. As a silly example, the statement $n\leq n$ for all naturals $n$ has base case $1=1$, but no case where the inequality is strict.

Comment: Depends on the question. In this case, showing $n=1$ is enough. Why? Because if you show $\geq$ in the inductive step, that means that you can show $n=2$ using $n=1$. Some induction problems will require multiple base cases, or more careful reasoning about $\geq$.

Comment: The related statement where you *would* have needed the two base cases would have been proving $5^n=1+4n$ for $n=1$ and $5^n>1+4n$ for all $n>1$.  You weren't asked this however.

Comment: No... that wouldn't make any sense.  If the induction step for equal worked then they would never *not* be equal.  And if the induction step for inequality worked for inequality then then would never *not* be equal. ANd them being equal for $n$ but inequal for $n+1$ but equal again for $n+2$ is hypothetically possible.  .... Not $\ge$ does not mean equal *AND* greater than.  It means equal *OR* greater than.... But what happens here it is only equal and $n=1$.  They get further and further apart.